# How to describe possible error codes returned by gRPC .proto schema

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc

Right now I'm using comment so client can know about what error need to be handle carefully:

```
service UserService {
    // INVALID_ARGUMENT: if token is in wrong format
    // NOT_FOUND: if user specific by UpdateUserDeviceTokenRequest not found
    rpc UpdateUserDeviceToken(UpdateUserDeviceTokenRequest) returns (UpdateUserDeviceTokenResponse);
}
```

Is there any other way?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Comments are the only way to convey this kind of information to the author of the client library.  Note that some errors may be generated by gRPC server and client library code, or that proxies between the client and server could generate errors, so the client must be ready for more errors than you list in your method's description.  You may also be interested in reading: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/statuscodes.md